What does "neither" here refer to?
In Killers Of The Flower Moon (2023), Ernest tells Ramsey about a job offer from King Bill Hale to eliminate someone.
Ramsey initially refuses, but when he learns the target is an Indian, he changes
his mind. Ernest further sweetens the deal by offering to buy Ramsey a roadster
for the job, even though Ramsey doesn't know Henry Roan:

Ramsey: It's gonna take a lot more than a roadster to get me out of
the bind I'm in.
Ernest: Well, we'll work something out. I hope you don't rumble over
this killing neither. The Indian, he's--He's a melancholic.

What does "neither" here refer to?

Some people (especially, Americans, imho) use neither where most of us would use either. Ernest means that as well as "working something out", he also hopes that Ramsey won't "rumble" (gangster-specific slang probably meaning "become concerned", but possibly "talk to the police", I dunno). Because the thing he's talking about is negated (don't rumble), Ernest uses neither / either rather than too, as well.

I agree with @FumbleFingers and add that even in America it is quite nonstandard. And I ain’t kiddin’ about that neither.

It should be "either" in all standard varieties of English.  However it's a feature of some American dialects (and some others such as Cockney/East London) to use double negatives like "don't . . . neither", and "ain't got nothin", etc, etc.

It's a non-standard double negative found on both sides of the Atlantic. “No sir; but it isn’t what they’d a right to expect, it isn’t,” said Bob, only half understanding me and repeating the lesson long drilled into him. “It isn’t what they’d a right to look for. They was the Old Family, as belonged to the Big House, and father, he always calls ‘em “Our Family,” ‘cause he don’t like new folks, nor new faces, nor new doings. Nor I don t neither, nor nobody here don’t”   Our Folks; John Churchill's Letters Home
by Agnes Giberne (London, 1882?)
